# Error adding a new feature for prediction using keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I did a prediction by using only number of Beds (worked fine), now, I'd like to improve the house pricing by adding a second input (Square Feet).

I added the code as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[2])])
xs = np.stack([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]], axis=1)
ys = np.array([100000, 150000, 200000, 250000, 300000, 350000], dtype=float)
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=100)
print(model.predict([[7.0], [400.0]]))  # [7.0] number of beds / [400] square feet
```

But I'm getting the error below:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_57 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

Please, need your support to fix it and make it working.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed following things from your code:

1. You need to compile your model before fitting/training it (see `model.compile('adam', 'mae')` in my code below)
2. The input array of which you wanted to predict had the wrong dimensions. It had dimension `(2,1)` which I changed to dimension `(1,2)`.

If I change these two things, the code works for me.

```py
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[2])])
xs = np.stack([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]], axis=1)
ys = np.array([100000, 150000, 200000, 250000, 300000, 350000], dtype = float)
model.compile('adam', 'mae')
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=100)
print(model.predict(np.array([[7.0, 400.0]]))) # [7.0] number of beds / [400] square feet #
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it worked :), also, I changed 'adam' to 'sgd' and got a better Loss.